# Instagram recent tag

Tags: php, mysql, tags, instagram

So I'm working with the Instagram API and using the recent tag call. The problem is I just want photos from today. I looked through the docs and the only parameters you can pass to the api are max_tag_id and min_tag_id. What would be the best method to insure I only get pics from today and not have to save every max_id to reference in my next call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way I fixed this was to not supply a min or max ID. Supplying these IDs will iterate through the most recent tag's 'pagination', not supplying them will bring back the most recent tags.

http://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent

Comment: Glad you solved this.  Please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so others can learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can provide a timestamp range according to the [API Documentation](http://instagr.am/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search).  Alternatively, you can just accept everything the API call returns and use a little logic on your end to filter the results.  Can you show us your code and what the API reply looks like, so we can provide better guidance?

Comment: I just wanted to bring back photos that have a certain tag, not everything in a certain time range.

Comment: I just didn't supply a max or min id and its pulling back the latest tags. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it's working.  If my answer helped you, please mark it as 'accepted'.  Otherwise, please take a moment to write up your solution as an answer and accept it so that others will see that this problem has been solved.  Cheers~